# I have a piece of server-client code, however this bit is in AS3 and I'm working in C#. Can someone help me translate it?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, code-translation

I've been working on converting an old server from a Flash game into something I can use as a starting point for a new server-client system, however I just hit a stopping point I can't really figure out. Can someone look at this code and possibly translate it into C#?

```
var dists:Array = [];
for(a=0;a<deltas.length;a++) {
    dists.push({offset:Math.abs(deltas[a]-avg), 
                time:deltas[a], 
                toString:function(){
                     return "offset:" + 
                     this.offset + ", 
                     time: " + this.time }
               })
}
```

As a note, these numbers are doubles - aside from the int in the for loop. And further clarification, Dists I've translated into a double list array, but that might be wrong. This is what I have so far:

```
List<Double> Dist = new List<double>();

for (int i = 0; i < Deltas.Count; i++)
{
    Dist.Add(Math.Abs(Deltas[i] - Average));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information given, this is what I could work out...

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int, double> deltas = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    int avg = 0;

    List<Item> dists = new List<Item>();
    for (int a = 0; a < deltas.Count(); a++)
    {
        dists.Add(new Item { Offset = Math.Abs(deltas[a] - avg), Time = deltas[a].ToDateTime()});
    }
}

public class Item 
{
    public double Offset { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string DisplayString { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("offset: {0}, time: {1}", this.Offset, this.Time);
    }
}

public static class Extension
{
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this double time)
    {
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aydin, that's what I was thinking as well, that the array translated into a Dictonary. One thing about Flash AS3 is that it's Array feature had so many more functions that it makes guessing what array translates into which in a more strictly typed language confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a new array `dists`:

> `var dists:Array = [];`

For each value in `deltas`:

> `for( a=0;a<deltas.length;a++){`

Insert a new object into the `dists` array:

> `dists.push(...)`

The object will have two properties - `offset` and `time` - and will have a `toString()` method that formats the data in a friendly way.

The `offset` value will be the difference between the current delta and the average:

> `offset:Math.abs(deltas[a]-avg)`

And the `time` value will be the current delta:

> `time:deltas[a]`